# How to get fancyhdr to correctly display my acro list of abbreviations chapter title, not the previous chapter's title?

Tags: fancyhdr, acro

Excuse the spaghetti code to make this MWE, but my report has a list of abbreviations before the list of contents and main body but after the list of tables.

The list of tables chapter name overflows into the list of abbreviations chapter and shows in the header. I want to keep using acro to display my abbreviations in the exact same way if possible but not have this occur. I also don't want the list of abbreviations appearing in the list of contents.

Here is my MWE where chapter 1 in the header overflows into where I generate my list of abbreviations.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\acsetup{pages/display=all,make-links=true,list/template = longtable,list/heading=chapter*,list/name={List of Abbreviations},pages/name=true}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM1}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM2}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM3}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM4}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM5}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM6}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM7}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM8}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM9}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM10}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM11}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM12}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM13}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM14}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM15}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM16}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}
\DeclareAcronym{STEM17}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM18}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}
\DeclareAcronym{STEM19}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM20}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM21}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM22}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM23}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM24}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM25}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM26}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM27}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM28}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM29}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM30}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM31}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM32}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM33}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM34}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM35}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM36}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\DeclareAcronym{STEM37}{
short = STEM,
long  = science technology engineering and mathematics,
tag = acronym
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Chapter}

\lipsum[]{4}

\newpage
\acuseall
\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

I have tried using \renewcommand\chaptername{} or whatever it is, but that changes the continuity of the chapter names for my report! I have also very messily attempted to drop in glossaries to try and fix this, but it hasn't worked for me.

Would appreciate any help! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\markboth{\acrolistname}{\acrolistname}` to the part that print the acronym list:

```
\newpage
\acuseall
\markboth{\acrolistname}{\acrolistname} %<<<<<< added
\printacronyms
```

Comment: Ahh it's perfect Pieter! Thank you